# HTML Navigation bar doesn´t work although using template code

Tags: html, navigationbar

I´m programming an HTML-Webside with phase-5 HTML-Editor and I want to make an horizontal Navigation bar. It still doesn´t work although I already pasted code of other programmers in it still is shown as a normal vertical list.
Here´s the HTML-Code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Webiste-Title</title>
 <link href="Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="Headbanner">
 <h1>Welcome</h1>
 </div>

 <div style="border:1px solid blue;" >
 <ul id="navi" style="display:inline;list-style-type:none;min-width:720em
 width:size 600px;position:absolute;" >
 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="chronik.html">Chronik</a></li>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

The imported CSS is empty except a color-change for h1. I can´t post images yet, but it shows the wanted Navigation-bar as a vertical list.

I looked in other Threads, but nothing worked.
Thank all off you who try to help already.

Tim Vahlbrock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  HTML
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul id="navlist">
<li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

CSS
#navlist li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: but do id="active"> and the id="current" have any special function? because you didn´t list them in the CSS

Comment: No special functions. Just names i gave them. Pelase click the green `ANSWERED` mark on the left of your post, so people now this is the answer on your question. best regards

Answer (score 0):

This style will solve  your problem

```
#navi li{
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    min-width:720em;
     width:600px;
    }
```

Click for fiddle :[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96nfqh9g/)

Comment: No problem. Is this the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Yes but i used the ans of krooy_mans beacause it was easier to copy &paste